# Spring per-environment configuration where PropertyPlaceholder is not enough

Tags: java, spring

I am configuring my spring application per-environemnt and I came to following problem:

As long as the environment changes just bean constructor/properties values I am fine with using `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`.

Now I am facing the fact that the bean structure itself change in different environemnts. E.g. in test environemnt I define single bean where in production environment I define another bean of same interface which requires property of type List set - in another words different structure where `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` can't really help.

I went with defining per-environment spring xml configuration importing it via `<import resource="myDefinition-${Environment}.xml />`. This is also fine until I want have it optional. The resource I am defining there is `@Autowired(required = false)` to another bean.

Since `<import ... />` doesn't allow optional attribute (as can be seen here: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-1624) I ended up having empty .xml configuration files for environemnts where I don't require having that bean. This is somewhat inconvenient.

Could anyone advice on best practice in such scenario?

Thanks.

Comment: IMHO, using different beans for test and prod means running different code in test and prod, which is not a good idea in my view.  Could you not use a bean with the list property for test?

Comment: How about if you need the same been which has list property but in TEST you use 1 item where in PROD many items? I think the problem is somewhat general, you can't always have exactly same bean definitions in all environemnts (as far to my experience).

Comment: In that case why wouldn't you have a list with only 1 item for TEST?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bean definition profiles, introduced in Spring 3.1 are designed to solve just this kind of problem. See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RC2/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.1.html

Comment: That look good but it is stil RC so I want be allowed to use it. Still thanks for the good tip. +1

Comment: 3.1 went final in December. http://blog.springsource.org/2011/12/13/spring-framework-3-1-goes-ga

Comment: Oh, my bad than. Thanks for all of it.